# Compare 2 CSV files using MS Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, comparison

I have 2 CSV files generated as outputs from 2 different Powershell scripts.

CSV 1 - has 2 columns Record ID and Account Name.

CSV 2 - has 2 columns Account Name and Path

I now have to compare the Account Names in both CSV files and output the matching Account names and their respective Record ID and Path to a new CSV file. This comparison and output has to be done using MS Powershell.

Any guidance on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. It will loop through the second file for each row in the first file and compare the account names. If it is a match it will add it to `$combine` which is exported to a new csv at the end.

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path ".\1.csv"
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path ".\2.csv"
$combine = @()

foreach ($first in $csv1) {
  foreach ($second in $csv2) {
    if ($second.'Account Name' -eq $first.'Account Name') {
        $match = New-Object PSObject
        $match | Add-Member Noteproperty "Account Name" $first.'Account Name'
        $match | Add-Member Noteproperty "Record ID" $first.'Record ID'
        $match | Add-Member Noteproperty "Path" $second.Path
        $combine += $match
    }
  }
}
$combine | Export-Csv -Path ".\combined.csv"
```

Comment: Exactly what i want.Works perfectly except that few items are duplicated in combined.csv,will check that